# Custom view with button in ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, view, android-arrayadapter

I have defined a custom view (xml) for my `ArrayAdapter` for a `ListView`, which adds a `Button`. I'd like to create an `OnClickListener` for this `Button` per row, but without creating a custom adapter. Is that possible, or does Android force me to create a custom `ArrayAdapter` for my `ListView`?

Here's a snippet of what I'm doing:

> ```
> glAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Group>(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_grouprow, R.id.groupRowText, ListOfGroups);
> ListView groupListView = (ListView)mainView.findViewById(R.id.listViewGroupMain);
> groupListView.setAdapter(glAdapter);
> groupListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
>     @Override
>       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
>           // Call function
>       }
> });
> ```

Now I'd like to add an `OnClickListener` for the `Button` in my custom view.

Comment: Post the code of your adapter, it depends of your implementation. You can handle the clicklistener in your adapter or in your object class directly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just added a code snippet.

Comment: @LaVomit you need to override `getview`. its better to have a custom adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement you own Adapter and in `getView()` method set `OnClickListener` on your button. Here kick off example:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Integer> {
    private ListView listView;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, Integer[] objects, ListView listView) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.listView = listView;
    }


    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
        Button btn;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Integer color = getItem(position);

        View rowView = convertView;

        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) getContext()).getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_row, parent, false);
            ViewHolder h = new ViewHolder();
            h.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
            h.btn = rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn);
            rowView.setTag(h);
        }

        ViewHolder h = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();

        h.text.setText(color);
        h.indicator.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // DO what you want to recieve on btn click there.
            }
        });

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

ViewHolder here for optimization. You can read about this [there](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html).

Comment: Off to writing a custom `ArrayAdapter` again, which I deleted before, hehehe. Thanks!!